# Cairo-Dock - Can't drag launcher to stack

Tags: cairo-dock

I have the latest version of cairo-dock , and I can't add launchers to stack item.
How can I copy application launchers onto the stack item ? 
The drag-and-drop feature doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just launch the application when it appears on a launcher ***right click*** on it and in *drop down menu* hover onto *application's name* and choose ***make it launcher***.

Also from the same menu you can transfer app launchers to other docks if you have more than one.

To add files to a *Stack* folder go to *Cairo configuration* right click on *cairo-dock* then in *search* field type *stack* and ***enable*** the module the Stack folder will appear on your *cairo-dock* to *drag & drop* files, images etc. to Stack folder you have to drag them from desktop or folders for example for application's path */usr/share/applications* and drag the icons you want to the Stack folder or */home/yourname/Pictures* for images, etc.

Comment: But the problem is that I can't drag the launcher item to the stack.

Comment: do you have your icons locked? if you locked the icon's position you cannot drag them anywhere.

Comment: Also *stack module* has to be *enabled* in *Cairo-dock* configuration.

Comment: I can drag it, but not to the Stack element. It just let me change the positions of the new launcher and the Stack element

Comment: please see my edited answer

Comment: it's enabled. when I drag the launcher onto it, and try to launch it , it opens it as a .desktop file